# Sort the column based on the name, which contains the date

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have the following data:

`df <- data.frame(id = c(0101, 1011, 2301), flat = c(1, 11, 1), buid = c(1, 10, 23), X2019.12.31.23.59.59 = c(14.123, 12.53, 8.53), X2020.01.31.23.59.59  = c(15.03, 14.63, 9.53), X30.04.2019.23.59 = c(21.03, 17.67, 7.27))`

I need to arrange the columns in order of the date that is written in the name of the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution would be to separate date and non-date columns, sort the date columns according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62848694/3962914.) answer and combine them.

```
library(lubridate)
date_cols <- grep('X\\d+\\.\\d+\\d+', names(df), value = TRUE)
non_date_cols <- grep('X\\d+\\.\\d+\\d+', names(df), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)

date_cols <- date_cols[order(as.Date(parse_date_time(sub('^X', '', 
                       date_cols), c('YmdHMS', 'dmyHM'))))]
df[c(non_date_cols, date_cols)]
```

---

To keep only unique date columns we can do :

```
cols <- as.Date(parse_date_time(sub('^X', '', date_cols), c('YmdHMS', 'dmyHM')))
df[c(non_date_cols, date_cols[!duplicated(cols)])]
```

Comment: I like the first solution, but it was not effective. I used a more general solution. 

After I ordered the data, it turned out that some columns (dates) are duplicated. How do you delete them to keep unique data?

Comment: You mean you have column with same names? Perhaps, you can use `sort` and then `unique` instead of `order` to keep unique dates.

Comment: Column names may be different. For me, the date (without time) hidden in the column name is important.
For example:
[24] "X2019.11.30.23.59.59"
[25] "X30.11.2019.23.59"

Comment: But what if two columns with same date have different values? You'll lose information in one of the columns if you keep only one column and which column would you keep?

Comment: More interesting is the column with less NA. But the solution maintaining the first column is also very good.

Comment: See updated answer to get the first column of each date.

Comment: Fantastic Tips.
Thank you for your solution and your time.